# Reclassify a raster tif to unique values

Tags: r

I have a raster tif file with unique values: `0,2,4,5,9,111,114,115,116,124,125,126`. 
I need to reclassify my raster cell values to be:
`0,2,4,5,9,4,4,4,4,4,4,4`.

I used the following codes:

```
is<-c(0,2,4,5,9,111,114,115,116,124,125,126)
become<-c(0,2,4,5,9,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
recMat<-matrix(c(is,become),ncol=2,nrow=12)
LU_AOI_2 <- reclassify(LU_AOI, recMat)# Reclassify
```

After the reclassification is done, when I plot my raster, I still see floating values. I need a raster with those unique values `(0,2,4,5,9,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)` only.
What is wrong with my codes? Why can I not make a raster with unique integer values?
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example data

```
library(terra)
is <- c(0,2,4,5,9,111,114,115,116,124,125,126)
become <- c(0,2,4,5,9,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
set.seed(1)
r <- rast(nrow=10, ncol=10, vals=sample(is, 100, replace=TRUE))
```

Two solutions:

```
x <- subst(r, is, become)
y <- classify(r, cbind(is, become))

unique(x)
#  lyr.1
#1     0
#2     2
#3     4
#4     5
#5     9

plot(x)
```

[image]

If that does not work with your data, then perhaps the input values are not whole numbers. In that case, you can either use a "from-to-becomes" matrix, or round your input data.

```
x <- subst(round(r), is, become)
```